# Fowarding port in iptables to internal server

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables, port-forwarding, linux-networking

I'm running cPanel/WHM with ConfigServer Firewall (csf).

I want to forward port 8080 on my webserver to an internal server with an IP of lets say 10.1.1.1 thats running a webserver on port 80. How can I do this?

My WAN ip is running on eth0
The internal server is connected using the eth1 interface.

What would be the appropriate IPtables cmd to do this?