# Fowarding port in iptables to internal server

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables

I'm running cPanel/WHM with ConfigServer Firewall (csf).

I want to forward port 8080 on my webserver to an internal server with an IP of lets say 10.1.1.1 thats running a webserver on port 80. How can I do this?

My WAN ip is running on eth0 The internal server is connected using the eth1 interface.

What would be the appropriate IPtables cmd to do this?

Comment: Dup of: http://serverfault.com/questions/289205/fowarding-port-in-iptables-to-internal-server

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work

```
sudo /sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.1.1.1:80
```

If you haven't already done so you may need to enable IP forwarding too

```
/sbin/sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

and to make it permanent edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` and set

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

EDIT:

As the policy on your FORWARD chain is DROP you will need to allow packets through. I don't think your current FORWARD rule is doing anything helpful so delete it.

Enable packets sent to FORWARD from eth0:8080 to be sent to 10.1.1.1

```
/sbin/iptables -I FORWARD  -p tcp -m tcp  -d 10.1.1.1 --destination-port 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Allow packets to go the other way too

```
/sbin/iptables -I FORWARD -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp -j ACCEPT
```

You mat want to restrict the latter further.

Comment: Will that actually working considering the 10.1.1.1 ip is on eth1?

Comment: Didn't seem to work.

Comment: @WilliamBalkcom: yes, you are routing packets from eth0:8080 -> 10.1.1.1:80 or at leasts that's what you requests. This works on a test system I have. Check that you have something listening on 10.1.1.1:80. Is 10.1.1.1 running a firewall and is it allowing connections on port 80 ? Check that your FORWARD chain is allowing packets.

Comment: I have a webserver listening on 10.1.1.1:80, it is allowing all connections. The connection to 10.1.1.1 is established through eth1 and eth1 is configured like this: http://gyazo.com/42a58b08b6d2dcbd1bee2b5148a478e6.png 

And actually the IP is 10.1.3.98, just using 10.1.1.1 as an example.

Comment: @WilliamBalkcom: please post the (suitably redacted) output of `iptables -l -v -n` and `iptables -t nat -L -v -n`

Comment: iptables -L -t nat output: http://pastebin.com/0hf929mU
iptables -L -v -n output: http://pastebin.com/jJJ3QxRY

Comment: See my edit for setting up the FORWARD chain

Comment: Still not working. http://pastebin.com/5qgtLrRM

Comment: Also here's prerouting: http://pastebin.com/bV4hn9nT

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth1 -p tcp \ 
  --dport 8888 -j DNAT --to 10.1.1.1:80
```

Sends forwards the requests on port 8888.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 8888 -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
```

Allows incoming connections ton port 8888.